# PWA launch icon update

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps

Problem: my PWA is already installed on many clients, Android and iOS, and I want to update the launch icon and splash screen.

**Android**: according to Google [documentation](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/):

> When the PWA is launched, Chrome determines the last time the local
> manifest was checked for changes. If the manifest hasn't been checked
> in the last 24 hours, Chrome will schedule a network request for the
> manifest, then compare it against the local copy.
>
> If select properties in the manifest have changed (see list below),
> Chrome queues the new manifest, and after all windows of the PWA have
> been closed, the device is plugged in, and connected to WiFi, Chrome
> requests an updated WebAPK from the server. Once updated, all fields
> from the new manifest are used.
>
> Which properties will trigger an update? background_color, display, orientation, scope, shortcuts, start_url, theme_color, web_share_target

In my tests, when I update one of these fields in the manifest (I am updating `background_color` for Chrome to pick up the change and the images specified in `icons\src` with the new icon), it will indeed be picked up after some time (I can see it by navigating to `chrome://webapks`) but the launch icon will NOT be updated. I have tried changing the icon name in addition to the icon content but that does not help.

Notes:

1. if I follow the instructions in [Testing manifest updates](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/#cr-android-test) then the icon will indeed be updated after some time, but obviously, I can't ask this to my users...
2. My PWA is listed in the installed apps in Android's settings

**iOS**: here the icon is specified in an HTML tag `apple-touch-icon` and I could not find anything except [this very old answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587882/is-it-possible-to-force-iphone-ipod-to-update-apple-touch-icon-once-webapp-is-ad):

> In newer iterations of iOS, the Apple Touch Icon that is displayed on
> the home screen is cached just like any other piece of content from the
> website. By simply changing the name of the image, it will force the
> home screen shortcut to refresh the icon the next time the shortcut is
> launched.

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href=".\icon.ico">
```

Again this is not what I am seeing, the icon will not change even if I modify the name of the referenced image.

What am I missing???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52156729/11647620

Comment: Not relevant, see my notes in the Android section

Comment: Note that for at least Chrome for Android there is bug/issue list to check: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=android%20webapk%20manifest%20icon%20pwa&can=1 for similar problems and should you wish to file: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines